# Add ParsleyJS custom message with field name

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

How can I set a default message which uses the name of the field and includes it in the error message. For example, instead of **"This value is required."** I would like to show **"First name is required."**. Where field name could be **first_name** or **firstName**.

I know you can do this by adding `data-parsley-required-message="First name is required"` but I don't want to do it for every field and all of its constraints. I would like this behavior by default.

Since we can set the default values like this:

```
window.Parsley.addMessages("en", {
    required: "This value is required.",
});
```

I would think the syntax would be similar to:

```
window.Parsley.addMessages("en", {
    required: "{name} value is required.",
});
```

I am moving from **jquery-validation** which does this out of the box. I think its a better description structure for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't handled by Parsley.